# Draw a projected rectangle on a map using d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, map-projections

which is the most elegant way to draw a projected rectangle on a map using **d3.js**?

This solution is good for circles

```
   var circ = d3.geo.circle();

    var circle = g.selectAll("path1")
        .data(dataset)

    circle.enter()
      .append("path")
        .attr("class", "point")
        .datum(function(d) {
            return circ
                .origin([d.x, d.y])
                .angle(3)()
        })
        .attr("d", path)
```

as well explained in "[Circle clip and projection with D3 orthographic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778856/circle-clip-and-projection-with-d3-orthographic)"

Anyway, apparently there is not a `d3.geo.rect()`, and I really cannot figure out which is the correct input that `d3.geo.path()` wants to operate.

Let's take for example this set of coordinates:

```
    var route = {
        type: "LineString",
        coordinates: [
            [0,0],
            [0,60],
            [60,60],
            [60,0],
        ]
    }

    svg.append("path")
        .datum(route)
        .attr("class", "route")
        .attr("d", path);
```

which results in this projected rectangle:
[image]

You can see that the upper line is bended and do not follow the projection. It sounds coorect, as it follows a geodesic (parallels are defined differently from meridians), but then how can I define a a line following a parallel?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If you want to use the rectangle to highlight something rather than show a geographic feature, it might be easier to draw it unprojected.