# Plotting on D3 projection

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Using [this](https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/rotate/) as the basis, how do I add markers? I can add points from a csv, but they do not rotate with the globe.

Inside the drawMap function, I've added:

```
d3.csv("cities.csv", function(error, data) {
    console.log(data);
    svg.selectAll(".pin")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle", ".pin")
      .attr("r", 2)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + projection([
          d.lat,
          d.lon
        ]) + ")"
      });    

});
```

Which works to pin the points but they are static. Full script is below...

```
var degrees = 180 / Math.PI,
    width = 1000,
    height = 600;

var loader = d3.dispatch("world"), id = -1;

d3.selectAll("#map")
    .data([
      orthographicProjection(width, height)
          .scale(245)
          .translate([width / 2, height * .495]),
      d3.geo.eisenlohr()
          .precision(.1)
          .clipExtent([[1, 1], [width - 1, height - 1]])
          .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
          .scale(75)
          .rotate([0, -30])
    ])
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .each(function(projection) {
      var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection),
          svg = d3.select(this).call(drawMap, path, true);
      svg.selectAll(".foreground")
          .call(d3.geo.zoom().projection(projection)
            .scaleExtent([projection.scale() * .7, projection.scale() * 10])
            .on("zoom.redraw", function() {
              d3.event.sourceEvent.preventDefault();
              svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
            }));
      loader.on("world." + ++id, function() { svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path); });
    });

(function() {
  var width = 350, height = 350,
      projection0 = orthographicProjection(width, height),
      projection1 = orthographicProjection(width, height),
      path0 = d3.geo.path().projection(projection0),
      path1 = d3.geo.path().projection(projection1);


  function redrawComparison1() { comparison1.selectAll("path").attr("d", path1); }
})();



d3.json("../world-110m.json", function(error, world) {
  d3.selectAll("svg").insert("path", ".foreground")
      .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land))
      .attr("class", "land");
  d3.selectAll("svg").insert("path", ".foreground")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.countries))
      .attr("class", "mesh");

  loader.world();
});





function drawMap(svg, path, mousePoint) {
  var projection = path.projection();

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(d3.geo.graticule())
      .attr("class", "graticule")
      .attr("d", path);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum({type: "Sphere"})
      .attr("class", "foreground")
      .attr("d", path)
      .on("mousedown.grab", function() {
        var point;
        if (mousePoint) point = svg.insert("path", ".foreground")
            .datum({type: "Point", coordinates: projection.invert(d3.mouse(this))})
            .attr("class", "point")
            .attr("d", path);
        var path = d3.select(this).classed("zooming", true),
            w = d3.select(window).on("mouseup.grab", function() {
              path.classed("zooming", false);
              w.on("mouseup.grab", null);
              if (mousePoint) point.remove();
            });
      });
d3.csv("cities.csv", function(error, data) {
    console.log(data);
    svg.selectAll(".pin")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle", ".pin")
      .attr("r", 2)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + projection([
          d.lat,
          d.lon
        ]) + ")"
      });


});

}
function orthographicProjection(width, height) {
  return d3.geo.orthographic()
      .precision(.5)
      .clipAngle(90)
      .clipExtent([[1, 1], [width - 1, height - 1]])
      .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
      .scale(width / 2 - 10)
      .rotate([0, -30]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand your frustration.

Try this:

```
d3.csv("data/cities.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d){
     svg.insert("path", ".foreground")
    .datum({type: "Point", coordinates: [d['lon'], d['lat']]})
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("d", path);
  });
});
```

You need to assign the "d" element to the variable path.
Earlier in the example, path is bound to the function d3.geo.path(), this is what links it to the projection.

For me, the breakthrough clue was provided here:
[Circle clip and projection with D3 orthographic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778856/circle-clip-and-projection-with-d3-orthographic)

Comment: ok I admit that I don't know (yet) what your piece of code makes exactly different from the one of the example but it helped me in the same situation as the thread-started! thx :-)