# d3.geo.circle angle does not work?

Tags: d3.js

So, I've tried following Jason Davies' answer to the [Circle clip and projection with D3 orthographic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778856/circle-clip-and-projection-with-d3-orthographic/15805862#15805862) thread...

I've tried 3 different possibilities :

```
svg.append("g").attr("class","points")
  .selectAll("path")
    .data(places.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    //THIS COMMENTED PART DOES NOT WORK
    //though the console spits out an array
    /*.datum(function(d){
         console.log(d.geometry.coordinates)
         return d3.geo.circle()
           .origin(d.geometry.coordinates)
           .angle(2)
    })*/

    //THIS UNCOMMENTED PART WORKS
    //and places the circles accordingly with a fixed size radius
    .datum(d3.geo.circle()
      .origin(function(d){return d.geometry.coordinates})
      .angle(2)
    )

    //THIS COMMENTED PART DOES NOT WORK
    //which is a shame, as my goal is to change the angle of each circle
    /*.datum(d3.geo.circle()
          .origin(function(d){return d.geometry.coordinates})
          .angle(function(d){return 2})
    )*/

    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("d", path)
```

How do I get the last commented part to work so that I can change the radius of my circles? Thanx a lot.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work please? Any error messages? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: How it doesn't work : the circles are just not created... The first commented part doesn't give me any message error. The second commented part says : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined " I'm just trying to figure out why it seems I can't put a function with a return in my angle property.

Comment: You need a `function(d)` just after `.datum()` like in the first commented part.

Comment: I got it
.datum(function(d){
          var origin = d.geometry.coordinates
          var angle = avions[d.properties.index].total_morts/100
          return d3.geo.circle().angle(angle).origin(origin)()
          }
        )
THIS WORKS!! The trick is in the parenthesis at the end. Why is that, though??

Comment: Oh right, didn't see that -- `d3.geo.circle()` is a factory function (i.e. a function that returns a function) which you then still need to call.

Answer (score 0):

After updating to d3 version "5.7.0" I had same issue.
Fixed by using `geoCircle.center(center).radius(angle)` instead of `geo.circle().angle(angle)`.

[Here](https://bl.ocks.org/tlfrd/0880fbf1bc462d1f28d8514ed8371aea) you can find how it could work.